# React website not deploying to GitHub Pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, github-pages

I've been using **node.js/npm** to deploy my **React** website to **GitHub Pages** but an error keeps showing up and not sure how to approach it. I have been looking around for solutions but there doesn't seem to be anything for this particular scenario:

I run the `npm run build` command for the completed application and add the correct GitHub Pages scripts in my package.json file below -

```
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": "https://darstnfrd.github.io/portfolio",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

Afterwards, I run `npm install --save-dev gh-pages`. From here, when I run `npm run deploy` this error below keeps emerging -

```
> portfolio@0.1.0 deploy C:\Users\darren\Desktop\react2018\portfolio
> gh-pages -d build

events.js:183
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^

Error: spawn git ENOENT
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:686:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! portfolio@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the portfolio@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\darren\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-12T02_09_20_837Z-debug.log
```

My GitHub Pages repository is ready to go. Additional actions I've tried are `npm rm -rf node_modules`, `npm cache clean` and reinstalling bootstrap dependency.

What exactly is the error? If any more information is needed, please let me know. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why not use zeit or netlify for deployment. It's much easier on those platforms.

Comment: Which machine are you on? Windows or Mac?

Comment: What is `npm add` supposed to do?

Comment: He probably meant yarn add  - - dev

Comment: I'm using Windows 10

Comment: I've been able to solve this issue. I had already installed Git onto my system but needed to reboot the console. I found the answer here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3216

Comment: After rebooting, you might get another error: "Failed to get remote.origin.url (task must either be run in a git repository with a configured origin remote or must be configured with the "repo" option)." I solved this issue by making sure that my project was a Git repository and in the correct GitHub folder